# Rails 5: Why is Summernote appearing unstyled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, summernote

I'm adding summernote-rails https://github.com/summernote/summernote-rails to a project. I've followed the readme: installed the gems:

```
gem 'summernote-rails', 'current version number'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'     # required
```

My application.scss:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "summernote";
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
//= require summernote
```

I've added the script to posts/edit.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote();
  });
</script>
```

The page loads with the form but it is completely unstyled. Not a whiff of Bootstrap. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that Summernote is loaded? Are you sure that your HTML element has an ID of "summernote"? Are you sure that it's not the data-provider attribute as mentioned in the github docs?

Comment: I've tried both the basic and unobtrusive JS examples. I suspect I'm not importing the stylesheets correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was a rookie mistake. Forgot to include:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```